# VssServiceResponseException: Forbidden in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

I'm using Azure Pipelines to run automated tests via VSTest Platform (V2). The deployment group I'm using has no Internet access and is private. I have the task currently set up to run Nunit tests in the project via the test assemblies. The deployment group has VSTest Platform installed on it and I specify the path to vstest.console.exe in the task. The build artifact is downloaded from the pipeline.

The error I'm getting during the VSTest task is this:

`Unhandled exception ocurred: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Forbidden`

Followed by a stack trace and then this shortly after:

`Error: The process 'C:\agent\A1\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.164.2\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 3762504530`

I can attach the full log if need be, but I'm just trying to get some general direction at the moment.

First off, what is VssService? I'm assuming it has something to do with Visual Studio, but the only things I can find with the VSS acronym are Visual SourceSafe (Microsoft source control software from ~2005, so I really doubt that's it) and something to do with Cisco network switches.

Second, what is DTAExecutionHost?

Third, where can I find information on that error code?

Comment: The error `ssServiceResponseException: Forbidden` seems to be the  Project Collection Build Service ()" identity is not having sufficient permissions to publish test results or the proxy of your agent, check this thread: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7173 and https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/3837 for some helps. BTW, are you using TFS and private agent?

Comment: I've looked through those issues and I believe I've got everything configured to properly use the proxy, namely https://*.dev.azure.com. I am not using TFS, but possibly private agent, not sure what defines that exactly. It's a deployment group with agent version 2.163.1